# Explanation for quantile notations $c_{d-1,1-\alpha}$ $z_{1-\alpha/2}$

Tags: self-study

I have started to learn statistics and I came accross those notations:
$c_{d-1,1-\alpha}$ $z_{1-\alpha/2}$
the first one is the $\alpha$-th order quantile of the $\chi_2$ distribution and the second one is the $\alpha$-th order quantile of the normal (gaussian) distribution. What is the explanation behind those notations?

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605916/z-frac-alpha2-and-z-frac-alpha2-in-confidence-intervals/605932#605932

Comment: Welcome to CV, Sir Joan.  Could you tell us what would constitute an "explanation" for a *notation?*  All that is needed to justify any notation is a definition or description, although (this is subtler) some underlying theory is usually involved in showing that the notation makes sense.  In the present case that comes down to the definition of a quantile function.

Comment: @Zhanxiong thank you!